# Нужно ли выделять «независимо от того» запятыми с двух сторон?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, предлоги

Если ты хочешь быть успешным, ты должен уметь брать на себя ответственность(,) независимо от того, какие будут результаты, какой будет исход — позитивный или негативный.

Answer (score 4):

Возможны оба варианта.

Оборот с предлогом ***независимо от*** можно не обособлять, так как он **не располагается между подлежащим и сказуемым**, а также находится **в конце** главного предложения. В случае необособления перед оборотом не делается пауза.

Но вот что пишут в правилах.

[**ПУНКТУАЦИЯ ПРИ ОБОРОТАХ С НЕПЕРВООБРАЗНЫМИ ПРЕДЛОГАМИ**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach1)

> В спорных случаях окончательное решение о постановке знаков препинания принимает автор текста.
>
> **Некоторые закономерности**
>
> **Обычно обособляются** (за исключением тех случаев, когда оборот входит в состав сказуемого или тесно связан с ним по смыслу) обороты с отглагольными предлогами *включая, исключая, исходя из, начиная с, невзирая на, несмотря на, смотря по, судя по*, а также ограничительно-выделительные обороты с предлогами *вопреки, за исключением, кроме, **независимо от**, помимо*.

В Национальном корпусе русского языка в большинстве случаев запятая ставится, но в зависимости от интонации и расставленных акцентов автор вправе не обособлять этот оборот, чему есть подтверждающие примеры:

*Свободный же дух должен действовать **независимо от того**, какие силы преобладают и торжествуют.* [Н. А. Бердяев. Размышления о русской революции (1924)]

*Чайковский и его друзья рассудили совершенно верно, что нравственно развитая личность должна быть в основе всякой организации **независимо от того**, какой бы политический характер она потом ни приняла и какую бы программу деятельности она ни усвоила под влиянием событий.* [П. А. Кропоткин. Записки революционера (1902)]